# after invoking the Director::getInstance()->popScene() the schedule stopped to fire events

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I try to implement the simple pause current scene (the game level)
jump to main menu screen and when clicking the resume button , the game will resume from where it stooped.
i try to use 
my main class has static scene object

```
Scene* HelloWorld::scene = nullptr;
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);
    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
bool HelloWorld::init()
{

    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto menuItem1 = MenuItemImage::create(
                                           "Menu-128.png",
                                           "Menu-128.png",
                                           CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuItemCallback, this));

    menuItem1->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + menuItem1->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + visibleSize.height - menuItem1->getContentSize().height/2)); 


    auto menu1 = Menu::create(menuItem1, NULL);
    menu1->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    this->addChild(menu1, 200);

    this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::MainGameLoop)); 

    return true;
}
void HelloWorld::MainGameLoop(float dt)
{
    log("animation runnig .. ")
}
void HelloWorld::menuItemCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->pushScene(scene);
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(MenuLayer::createScene());
}
```

it jump to the MenuLayer scene just fine
but when i to go back from the MenuLayer to the HelloWorld ( the main scene ) 
the animation dosn't resume back , why ?
this is the code when i press the resume in the MenuLayer object

```
void MenuLayer::menuResumeCallback(Ref* pSender)
{

    Director::getInstance()->popScene();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pushing/popping *MenuLayer* scene:

```
void HelloWorld::menuItemCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->pushScene(MenuLayer::createScene());
}

void MenuLayer::menuResumeCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->popScene();
}
```

When *HelloWorld::menuItemCallback* is called *MenuLayer* scene is added to scene stack and on next step it will become a running scene. When You press the resume button *Director::popScene* is called and the only scene left in scene stack is your *HelloWorld* scene with previous state.